# How long is the wait period between Github student verification and access to academic benefits?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-copilot

**Problem Description:**
It shows on the Github website that I was verified as a student on Aug 23, 2023 successfully. Yet I can't use the student package now. I wonder how long is the waiting period between Github student verification and access to academic benefits?

**My questions:**
What is the average waiting time interval for everyone? Is there any channel to contact the official argument or urge? What is the time difference between approving student certification and being able to use student benefits? Thank you~

**The application & verification timeline:**

- I applied for Github student authentication on August 23, 2023. I uploaded the picture of my student card as verification material but wasn't approved at that time.
- On August 28, 2023, I uploaded the picture of proof of enrollment provided by the school as supporting material, and the image was approved.
- On August 30, 2023, I noticed that the student authentication on Github has been approved, but I still cannot use student packages such as Copilot.

The website states that "There may be a wait period between verification and access to academic benefits." But compared to the experiences of other students who apply for student packages online, their processing was very fast and they have all received emails (I have not received any emails regarding successful authentication yet).

The sceenshot is shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh7HG.png)